# ASIHTTPRequest requestFinished inside subclass never call

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, asihttprequest

`UIViewController` (*startHome*) use a subclass method (*invioDati*) to send username and password to a site. 
The sending with `ASIHTTPRequest` class work.
But I need, in the *startHome*, to know when the async is finished and if fail or success.

With my code, `requestFinished` is never call.

If i put all *invioDati* code inside *starHome* work great.

I cut off useless code from *starthome.m*, like UITextField add.

**startHome.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface startHome : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
{
UITextField  *regUtente, *regPassword;
}

-(void)inviaRegistrazione;

@end
```

**startHome.m**

```
#import "startHome.h"
#import "invioDati.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

--CODE CUT--

[invioDati invioDatiRegistrazione:regUtente.text password:regPassword.text];  
}
```

**invioDati.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ASIHTTPRequest.h"

@interface invioDati : NSObject <ASIHTTPRequestDelegate>


+(void)invioDatiRegistrazione: (NSString *)utente password:(NSString *)password;

@end
```

**invioDati.m**

```
#import "invioDati.h"
#import "ASIFormDataRequest.h"
#import "ASIHTTPRequest.h"

@implementation invioDati

+(void)invioDatiRegistrazione: (NSString *)utente password:(NSString *)password
{


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.siteaddress.com/page.php"];

ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setPostValue:utente forKey:@"utente"];
[request setPostValue:password forKey:@"password"];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed:)];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestFinished:)];
[request startAsynchronous];
 }

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
// this is called if the request is successful
NSLog(@"registerFinished %@",[request responseString]);
}

- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
// this is called if the request fails
NSLog(@"registerFailed %@", [request error]);
}

- (void)requestStarted:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{
// this is called if the request start
NSLog(@"request started");
}
@end
```

Comment: Please be aware that `ASIHttpRequest` has been depreciated for a long time now and has known bugs in iOS 7+. You should really move to another library like `AFNetworking`

Comment: ok thanks, i try to move to AFNetworking.